# How to pass value of javascript to Mako template

Tags: javascript, python, cherrypy, mako

I'm planning on server's cherrypy with programming of python and mako.
Now i have one problem because i know to pass value of Mako template to Javascript with

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var contapara=${input_nparams}; 
</script>
```

and viceversa? It 's possible apply viceversa Mako<---JAvascript?

Thanks

Edit:

Because I have one variable of Mako (kwargs) that contains the data of all forms sent.
The user enters a word that is the "clave" and is stored in Javascript.
After this I pass in Mako to search in variable (kwargs).
Call the function's MAko.
After exist this I open one windows with the textarea (new form) and I have to write data.
AFter the user change data and send the form.

Comment: What does this mean? What are you expecting to do with the Javascript value in the Mako template?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to understand what you're trying to do. Some code would probably be helpful.

Comment: It 's possible apply viceversa Mako<---JAvascript

Comment: passing from javascript to mako is ... difficult, because when javascript can be executed, mako is done. You probably just whant to send your value from javascript with the next request to the server. That would be done normally via a form (fill hidden field via JS or so), via loading a new page (with the value in the url as get) or via ajax.

Comment: jajajaja I look on this site http://indico-software.org/wiki/Dev/Technical/UsingMako.
And your answer is correct Kratenko.

Answer (score 1):

Make a view that takes in the arguments that you would want to send to mako, then in your javascript use ajax. for example:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url       : url_of_the_mako_view,
        data      : {foo:bar,foo2:bar2},
        type      : 'POST',
        success   : function(data)
        {
            /*
             when the mako template is rendered by your view then the result will
             be passed to this function in the variable data
            */
        }
    }
)
```

If you are after something a little more like a page redirect then you can do something more like this:

1. make a form that redirects to the right place
2. put in a hidden field
3. populate the hidden field with a json string representing the arguments you want to pass to mako
4. submit the form
   Then in the view that gets the form data you need to turn the json into a dictionary and pass that to mako

Comment: It's a possible solution but when I starting my project.
I have really this variable kwargs with date.
But for your solution and apply for <form method="GET">?

Comment: @begginnerofall: I've added form stuff to my answer

Comment: I searchig for use your solution.
I have to program of new server.

Comment: Dear Sheena, The instructions that you have left the edited response have already been made.
Thanks,
But now and how to possible changing this data when the user wrongs.
I haved the variable's dictionary.
I have to read this dictionary with Mako and open the new form with JS, Loading information on dictionary with Mako and writing data on textarea's form with Mako.
But all this I need passing value's Js a Mako that is not possible.
The solution is working on only Query string.
You have other solution?

Comment: @begginnerofall: I'm sorry, I still cant understand what you are asking. Can you please edit your question and explain there? Maybe draw a picture or something, I'll help if I can understand